# will locationListener work when application is off?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, timer

I want to send a GPS location to the server every 5 minutes,

Even when my application is off.

I understand AlertManager can preform this.

would it be the same efficiency wise to set a LocationMaanger with

minTime = 5 min
minGPS_delta = 0

in general when would you use:

1) View.postDelay();

2) LocationMaanger.setListener() with minTime = 5 min and minGPS_delta = 0

3) AlertManager

4) Timer

Comment: I have an app that do exactly the same you ask... what I'm doing... I implemented the locationManager into a service of the system... the services cannot be killed never.. and it is listening the location every five minutes... if you want I can share the code of the service here...

Comment: @geekCode service can be killed. it's killed together with the app it's been associated with

Comment: @geekCode would love to see your code

Comment: @mangusta and what about AlarmManager ? will be also disposed when application is shut down?

Comment: @mangusta the only way to kill the service I implemented it's if you uninstall the app, in the onDestroy method once it's called the service restart it self...

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.Telephony;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class MyService extends Service
{
    private static final String TAG = "BOOMBOOMTESTGPS";
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 300000;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 328.08f;
    String sLat;
    String sLong;
    String Speed;
    String sAlt;
    String sTime;
    String IMEI;
    String Phone;
    String LocationCode;
    String localTime;

    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
        Location mLastLocation;

        public LocationListener(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-7:00"));
            Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
            SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-7:00"));
            localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);
            sLat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
            sLong = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
            Speed = Double.toString(location.getSpeed());
            sAlt = Double.toString(location.getAltitude());
            sTime = Double.toString(location.getTime());
            Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location + localTime);
            mLastLocation.set(location);
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Latitude", sLat));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Longitude", sLong));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IMEI", IMEI));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ReportDate", localTime));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Altitude", sAlt));
            String res;
            String loc = URLEncoder.encode(IMEI);
            try {
                res = CustomHttpClient.sendData("url", nameValuePair);
                String resp = res.toString();
                resp = resp.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                Log.i(TAG, sLat + " , " + sLong + " , " + resp +" , "+ sAlt);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Coordenadas:"+sLat+", "+sLong+" Device IMEI: "+IMEI+" resp "+resp,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
        }
    }

    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Phone = preferences.getString("Phone", "");
        LocationCode = preferences.getString("LocationCode", "");
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        initializeLocationManager();
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[1]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[0]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        IMEI = mngr.getDeviceId();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                try {
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for late reply...

Comment: Came here to say "write a service", but you did even better than that.

Comment: thank you very much any further question I'll be more than happy to help =D